# Python Pandas: Compare ticks with differing intervals to hourly data

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I have a months worth of ticks at differing intervals in a pandas dataframe as follows

```
                         Spread
Date                           
2021-02-01 00:01:10.718     9.0
2021-02-01 00:01:14.471     9.2
2021-02-01 00:01:24.794     5.5
2021-02-01 00:01:30.738     4.6
2021-02-01 00:01:30.938     3.5
```

I also have an hourly threshold as follows

```
                        Upper
Date                         
2021-02-01 00:00:00  4.709884
2021-02-01 01:00:00  1.356615
2021-02-01 02:00:00  0.667457
2021-02-01 03:00:00  0.628824
2021-02-01 04:00:00  0.642154
```

My goal is to compare and find all ticks that are above the threshold for the given hour.
For example I want to compare all ticks between **2021-02-01 00:00:00** and **00:59:59** with the threshold for **2021-02-01 00:00:00** from the second dataframe and so on for the duration of the month.

I've tried using `groupby()` to group the ticks into **(date, hour)**, but I have no idea how to automate the process of finding values above the corresponding threshold for a whole months worth of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` is your friend here:

```
s = pd.merge_asof(df, hourly, on='Date')

# for references
df['Upper'] = s['Upper'].values

# we need to pass value because `merge_asof` reset the index
df['matched'] = (s['Spread'] <= s['Upper']).values
```

Output:

```
                         Spread     Upper  matched
Date                                              
2021-02-01 00:01:10.718     9.0  4.709884    False
2021-02-01 00:01:14.471     9.2  4.709884    False
2021-02-01 00:01:24.794     5.5  4.709884    False
2021-02-01 00:01:30.738     4.6  4.709884     True
2021-02-01 00:01:30.938     3.5  4.709884     True
```

**Note**: If you have different ticks, you can pass `by='tick'` to `merge_asof`.